# Is NSIndexPath only purpose to initialize objects to be used in UITableView instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is a method defined in my interface file. I have a "new" button and when it's clicked it adds a new row to my UITableView instance.

1. I'd like to know if NSIndexPath is only used for create objects to be used with UITableViews or if it has other purposes?
2. Also in my code or in general does `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation];` work by taking the newly updated array and re-displaying it's data on the view? It doesn't look that way when the new row is added unless it happens very quickly. Also part of the method says insert "rows" at "indexPaths".

I'm thinking maybe since the array of objects and the indexPaths would have matching indexes maybe when that array is passed in as an argument some code in the background get's the position of the row and uses that to know where to insert it in the table. Maybe it knows the existing table will have 1 less item than the array then insert it using the index that comes after the last object in the visible table?

Maybe it checks if a row already exists at that indexPath and if it does then do nothing, if it doesn't then add that row with an animation?

Yes I'm confused :-|

Hopefully you guys can help clear this up for me.

```
// add a new item to the table
- (void)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
    // Create a new BNRItem and add it to the store
    BNRItem *newItem = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem];

    // Figure out where that item is in the array
    int lastRow = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] indexOfObject:newItem];

    // Returns index-path object initialized, ready to be inserted into table
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastRow inSection:0];

    // Insert this new row into the table
    [[self tableViewinsertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation]:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}
```

Thanks for your time.
Kind regards

Comment: Strange thing to say as it predates iOS by quite a few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a class part of Foundation and is used to describe a path in a tree.  At each level, a node is addressed by its index.

So, in the context of your problem, `UITableView` needs `NSIndexPath` because it does not simply display a list of items.  It has sections — another level of indirection — and therefore you need to address sections first, and then an item inside a section.

I hope this will help you see clearer.